# Multiple ssl certificates for different domaines in Spring boot or tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot

I have one server with two domain names. Currently I use only one self signed certificate with such configuration in application.properties:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

I like to make register normally signed certificates for future using. But I don't understand how I may configure spring-boot or tomcat for that... There is a think to use **TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory** but will it working? If someone have such practice please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I configure Apache for two domaines with different certificates and make ProxyPass to spring-boot. Now it is working as I wanted.

Comment: Hi, I ran into a same issue, can you share more of your solution?

Comment: You may rise up nginx or apache http and configure it as a proxy to your application